# Two insert statements in php

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi guys how do I have two insert statements in the php codes to store the data into two different tables in the database?

```
$order = "INSERT INTO NewCase(CaseID, StaffName, Category, PriorityLevel, Status, Date, Summary, ResidentID)
VALUES (NULL, '$staffname', '$category', '$prioritylevel', '$status', '$checkdate', '$summary', NULL)";

$order .= "INSERT INTO NewResident(ResidentID, NRIC, ResidentName, Telephone, Email, Gender, Street1, Street2, PostalCode)
VALUES (NULL, '$nric', '$residentname', '$telephone', NULL, NULL, '$street1', '$street2', '$postalcode')";

$retval = mysqli_multi_query($link, $order);
```

Comment: Take a look at [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using mysqli prepared statements and **nothing else**.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO NewCase VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL)";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss",$staffname, $category, $prioritylevel, $status, $checkdate, $summary);
$stmt->execute();

$sql = "INSERT INTO NewResident VALUES (NULL, ?,?,?, NULL, NULL, ?,?,?)";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss",$nric, $residentname, $telephone, $street1, $street2, $postalcode);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi it does not work as well.

Comment: If it doesn't work than you are doing something wrong. So you have to fix your code.

Comment: I made some changes to your codes, can you help me to see if there is any errors?

Comment: Yes, I can. These changes make absolutely no sense at whole.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look into transactions may be?
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($link, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

mysqli_query($link, $order1);
mysqli_query($link, $order2);

mysqli_commit($link);

mysqli_close($link);
```

Also if transaction fail you can always rollback

Also I suggest you use more Object Oriented approach:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "world");
$mysqli->query();
$mysqli->query();
$mysqli->close();
```